# Update Component from another component in Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

I have MainLayout which contains
`<StickyMenu>` component and @Body component

here the code of MainLayout

```
<header>
  <StickyMenu></StickyMenu>
</header>

<main>
  <Loader Loading=@IsLoading></Loader>
  @Body
</main>
```

In my Product page, that fills the @Body section, when something is added in the cart, I need to update the StickyMenu component.

Product.razor.cs

```
public async void AddToCart()
  {

       //add to cart code
       *** HERE I NEED TO UPDATE StickyMenu component ***
  }
```

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: For stuff like this I usually create a `CascadingApplicationState` component and wrap my entire app with it,  and use it as a parameter in any component that needs to fire events like this.

Comment: See many SO questions and answers on the topic - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77097917/in-my-blazor-server-app-i-want-to-show-messages-of-razor-cs-pages-in-the-header

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76864163/subscribe-to-an-eventcallback-from-a-layout-when-using-router

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69558006/how-can-i-trigger-refresh-my-main-razor-page-from-all-of-its-sub-components-wit

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76256650/i-need-to-update-state-of-blazor-component-when-other-component-changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a shared service - which I'll call `ICartService` - to act as a common receiver and publisher of events.

The cart service probably loads the user's cart from the database, and allows the cart to be managed. It also allows subscribers to be notified of future changes.

`CartService.cs`

```
// TODO: implement and register for dependency injection
public interface ICartService
{
  // event to allow components to listen for cart changes
  // look into using IObservable or other alternatives
  event EventHandler<CartEventArgs> CartChanged;
  
  // cart management methods
  void AddToCart(string product);  
  int GetTotalCount();
  void RemoveFromCart(string product);
}
```

The product page updates the cart.

`Product.razor`

```
<button @onclick="@AddToCart">Add to cart</button>

@inject ICartService CartService
@code {
  [Parameter]
  public string ProductName { get; set; }

  private void AddToCart()
  {
    CartService.AddToCart(ProductName);
  }
}
```

The menu can listen for changes and updates the item count.

`StickyMenu.razor`

```
@*Arbitrary component shows a possible usage of ItemCount*@
<MyCartIcon ItemCount="@ItemCount"></MyCartIcon>

@inject ICartService CartService
@code {
  private int ItemCount { get; set; }
  
  protected override void OnInitialized()
  { 
    ItemCount = CartService.GetTotalCount();

    // listen to future events
    CartService.CartChanged += OnCartChanged;
  }

  private void OnCartChanged(object sender, CartEventArgs args)
  {
    CartSize = CartService.GetTotalCount();
    // Notify Blazor that a re-render is required
    StateHasChanged();
  }
}
```

Working example: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/abqyhwhh

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with the cart it works. But in my StickuyMenu I have also an AutorizeView. Putting something in the cart I create also a fake user and I put it in the CustomAuthStateProvider. The AuthorizeView doesn't change. I try to edit the fiddle.

Comment: If you feel the answer has answered the original question then please mark as answered. If you have another question then please post a new question.

Comment: Yes the answer is right thanks